# Reloading .NET config file

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, configuration-files

I need to reload the configuration file after modifying it. How this can be done using appdomains? A code sample would be useful.

Comment: Do we really need to reload the config file after making some changes to it !?, I don't know, I am just asking, because I remember reading some where that we don't need to reload. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of program is this? Windows Service? ASP.NET?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reload configuration settings from an external config file during run-time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934898/reload-configuration-settings-from-an-external-config-file-during-run-time)

Answer (score 11):

Let's say you have the following config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="test" value="1" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Let's try the naive approach first.  The following application will try to grab the value of the `appSetting` named `test` once per second, and print its value:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while(true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test"]);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

But alas! While this is running, you'll notice it keeps printing `1`, and doesn't pick up any changes.

If you update your code to the following, it will fix this issue, and it will pick up changes whenever you change it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while(true)
    {
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
        Console.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test"]);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pity this post wasn't marked as answer. I tend to prefer more _verbose_ answers, but well, its just me.

Answer (score 9):

[`ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.refreshsection.aspx) might work for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
  ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("configuration");
  Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible... depending on **HOW** you access your configuration file.

If you rely on the default behavior, then the answer is **NO**.

However, if you access the configuration through a `static` property of method common to your project, then it's possible to reload it.

I don't have the code snippet with me now, but I did something similar even using a [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to detect changes in the `config` file.

There's one caveat, it works only with properties that you access directly through your code, automatic configuration will not be reloaded when you do such thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually found the solution to the given problem. Below are fiew lines of code of how this can be done:

```
            AppDomainSetup domaininfo = new AppDomainSetup();

            domaininfo.ApplicationBase = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            domaininfo.ConfigurationFile = "Target_Config.exe.config";

            Evidence adevidence = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence;

            AppDomain dom = AppDomain.CreateDomain("test", adevidence, domaininfo);

            var someType =(SomeType)dom.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("Target_Assembly", 
                "Target_Assembly.SomeType");
```

The key point here is the AppDomainSetup class, which allows to set the configurationfile property on the assembly to be created. Now, we can monitor the configuration file "Target_Config.exe.config" for changes. When it is changed, the above created appdomain should be unloaded and then recreated.

Comment: This is probably a solution to reusing a configuration file across several applications without copying it for each application.