# Where to store app configuration data that needs to be overwritten?

Tags: .net, app-config

I have a Console Application that needs to store `LastRunDate` (time when it was ran last time). It is common date for all users on a machine. Each time a user run this app this value should be updated.

Where to store that value? 
Using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`? This is read only.
Using settings file with serialized settings - Application scope? - This is also read-only User scope? - this will be different value for each user.

Comment: Here is how you can update values in AppSettings: [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/d68a872e-14bc-414a-82c4-d1035a11b4a8/) Update: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934898/reload-configuration-settings-from-an-external-config-file-during-run-time) to work with different settings files.

Comment: OK, but it does not work if one decide to store AppSettings section in separate file.

Comment: @jlp have you read my answer?

Comment: Updated with a link to answer that shows how you can work with different files.

Comment: What Massimilano Peluso is trying to show you is a cleaner solution. The walkthrough on the concept is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et91as27.aspx

Comment: `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` are not read only - you can write to them. I'm not sure its the correct place though. I would write a text file in the application directory.

Answer (score 2):

you could create a class that **encapsulate** all the properties you need - DateTime,user,etc that you can user the `Serialization` to "Save" the state of that object an `Deserialize` it when you need to update the state on the object (in your case the Last run Date)

more info at :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx

Comment: +1, that is a clean way to do this. Looks a bit harder than just messing with config files, but it is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Just store it in your [settings, user scoped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#settingscs_topic2), such as:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.LastRunDate = DateTime.Now;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

You can expand your 'Properties' node in Visual Studio to access the Settings and define this 'LastRunDate' setting.

Comment: It is only possible with User scope. But then each user will have its own date. It have to be one date.

Comment: Hm, understandable; though for something so simple you could simply write it to a dedicate file - if you even _need_ to do that: perhaps accessing the [last access date of the executable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastaccesstime(classic).aspx) would suit your needs, removing the requirement to store anything anywhere. This all depends on your situation.